# How to get current site id? (WPMU)

Tags: multisite, blog-id

I am using WordPress with MU activated. I found a function [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_site) that supposed to return an object with the current side ID. But it's returning 1 for all websites.

```
<?php get_current_site(); ?>
```

Comment: The doc block for that function is misleading/wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, `get_current_site()->blog_id` will return 1, as it refers to the network.

To get the current site (blog) ID you can go like this:

```
<?php echo get_current_blog_id(); ?>
```

Moreover you can get the current site (blog) details like this:

```
<?php var_dump(get_blog_details()->blog_id); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a place with documentation for all wpmu functions? Do the old functions (before MU became part of wordpress) still apply?

Comment: @gdaniel Yes, there is a page in the Codex about [WPMU functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions); as far as I know most of them do still apply :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether user belong from current site by using

```
 <?php is_user_member_of_blog( $user_id, $blog_id ); ?>
```

After you get id of user create user role

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
if ( $user ) {
$roles = $user->roles;
```

and in last create posts for every user by adding role in args. not tested but i'll do trick for you.

```
<?php
$args1 = array(
    'role' => 'subscriber',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$subscribers = get_users($args1);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->display_name.'['.$user->user_email . ']</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```